# Yii2 datetime difference calculation between two dates and inserting the difference in db

Tags: php, datetime, yii2, yii2-model

[image]

There are 3 fields in task table-> expected_start_datetime,expected_end_datetime,time_allocated
While creating a task expected start and end datetime is selected and saved in the records.

What I am trying to do is to find the difference between the two dates in hours and minutes and save the value inside the "time_allocated" while creating the task and later on the update or view page use/display the time allocated value from the records.

Trying something like this in the task controller action create

```
$diff = ((strtotime($model->expected_start_datetime) - strtotime($model->expected_end_datetime)) / (60 * 60 * 24));

        $model->time_allocated = $model->time_allocated + $diff;
```

[image]

Comment: evaluate the date difference before inserting data

Comment: @zahraj just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your model you should be override beforeSave function like this:

```
            public function beforeSave($insert) {

                $diff =strtotime($this->expected_end_datetime)-strtotime($this->expected_start_datetime);
                $hours= floor($diff/(60*60));
                $mins= floor(($diff-($hours*60*60))/60);

                $this->time_allocated=$hours.':'.sprintf("%02d",$mins);
                return parent::beforeSave($insert);
            }
```

Comment: one thing more it display as 04.55 what if want it show something like 04 hour and 55 minutes?

Comment: you can use explode for that

Comment: it saves as 14hour and 25minutes in DB.I mean is it a good practice to save it like this in the db?

Comment: No, the best thing is to using Unix Timestamp in your db and for displaying use some codes similar these codes

Comment: even if I am using your earlier approach the time difference I am getting is always wrong

Comment: can you explain more by an example

Comment: added screenshot of the wrong difference I am getting by using this $this->time_allocated =date('H:i',(strtotime($this->expected_end_datetime)-strtotime($this->expected_start_datetime)));

Comment: you have something on this?

Comment: +1 for using beforeSave.. Btw, if you are having trouble with validation, override beforeValidate instead of beforeSave